# How much battery does receiving a GCM message use?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

If I receive a GCM message in a BroadcastReceiver and then do some very basic logic, how much battery will that use? I am thinking around ~30 messages per day. What about data?

EDIT: I understand that different devices have different battery sizes and CPU efficiencies, etc. I'm not asking for a precise percentage used, more just "you should worry about that" vs "you don't have to worry".

The logic involves reading a long from the db (last sync time) and comparing it with current time.

The messages will mostly all be received in a span of ~4 minutes.

EDIT2: I guess what I am asking is is it worth it to limit/batch up the amount of push notifications that my server sends? Ideally, ignoring battery life, I would want my server should send a push notification every time new data gets updated. The phone can then decide whether or not to actually pull the updates from the server. If it doesn't decide to pull, then at least the phone knowingly decided to not update the data. As opposed to if I limit the amount of times my server sends push notifications to my phone to tell it there is new data, then the phone thinks it has updated data but it actually doesn't.

Comment: no way to tell, since every device has different cpus with different batteries and different power consumption specs. And your "basic logic" may very well be someone else's supercomputer job.

Comment: There is no way to adequately answer this question as it is written. The answer depends on what else is happening on the device (GCM messages are often batched), what the hardware specs of the device are, how big the user's battery is, and so much more.

Comment: I understand that different devices have different battery sizes and CPU efficiencies, etc. I'm not asking for a precise percentage used, more just "you should worry about that" vs "you don't have to worry".

The logic involves reading a long from the db (last sync time) and comparing it with current time.

The messages will mostly all be received in a span of ~4 minutes.

Comment: GCM is always active in your device. And your app subscribes to the service. The work that your app does can be an issue, but the message by itself don't :)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends. GCM can be received over Wifi, or over a cellular connection. The cellular radio consumes much more power than Wifi. Also there's a "warm up" and "keep alive" after each use of the radio, so sending/receiving things in one big burst is more energy efficient than sending them spaced a few minutes apart. This [Youtube video from GoogleDevelopers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEEulSk1kNY) has some more information about how to optimize network access to minimize battery consumption.

That said, the exact amount of power used will likely depend on the handset, distance to tower/Wifi access point, network protocol used (802.11g, CDMA, GSM, etc), and other factors.

Answer (score 1):

"you don't have to worry" is the  answer. GCM services is one process which manage push notification for all android app. It is for sure better than many different apps which ask continuosly to a remote server for new messages. It will use some battery percentage, but less than any other way

Comment: Not true, as the broadcast brings app to life, we all know cold startup costs battery life. Now imagine 50 apps on you phone were launched and later killed to give up the memory it occupied, the amount of battery this mechanism costs might be the reason why android battery life sucks at standby, relative to ios per say